# kubectl logs hangs and then times out

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2

When I run the kubectl command it hangs and then outputs an error which I've pasted below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-195:~$ kubectl logs nginx
Error from server: Get "https://172.31.6.112:10250/containerLogs/default/nginx/nginx": dial tcp 172.31.6.112:10250: i/o timeout
```

Here is my kube information:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-195:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx   1/1     Running   0          62m   192.168.43.76   ip-172-31-6-112   <none>           <none>
```